# Recommended way to run firebase firestore / storage locally in standalone application

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

As the title suggests, I've been trying to make an offline version of my web application that makes use of Firestore and Cloud Storage.

I've been trying to make the emulator suite run locally and I've been somewhat successful in doing this, but to run the emulator you need to have the [Java JDK installed as well as Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure). I'd prefer to not have the end-user require to install these two things to make use of my application.

Firestore also has an [offline caching system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) but I haven't been able to find a way yet to force this system to manually cache all the data I need for offline use. What approaches would be recommended to achieve my desired goal and are there examples of other people doing similar things?

Comment: For clarity, if this is a purely offline application, Firebase is not the right product. The intention of persistence is really for short-term or temporary outages - when you're using the app on a train and you go through a tunnel where the internet is interrupted for example. It's really not designed for long-term offline usage. The bigger issue is that Firebase is incredible scaleable and may contain thousands of gigabytes of data - storing all of that locally would be bad. Lastly, if you go beyond the default cache, firebase will 'clean up' unused documents - that could impact queries.

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't been able to find a way yet to force this system to manually cache all the data I need for offline use.

If you have the offline persistence mechanism enabled, which in Firestore is enabled by default for Android, and Apple. For web apps, offline persistence is disabled by default, so you should explicitly enable it. In each case, the client SDK will automatically create a cached copy of your database. There is no need to force anything.

When you're saying "all the data I need", you're thinking that you can choose which parts of your database should be present in the cache or not, then please note that this is not possible. It's the entire database or nothing, and unfortunately, this mechanism cannot be changed.

Comment: For web apps, offline is not enabled by default afaik: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yep, that's right. I just updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ForsakenCreator Can I help you with other information?

Comment: As far as I can see, the offline mode only caches data that's being queried actively. So I came to the conclusion that I'll have to port my firestore data to an offline database. Maybe you have any recommended Database? I'm currently exploring MongoDB.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations are forbidden here on StackOverflow, as there are opinion-based questions.

Comment: So did my answer help, can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?